# React Native inconsistent size of items in FlatList when using numColumns and margin

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, flatlist, react-native-stylesheet

When the last row has 1 or 2 items when using numColumns={3} they are slightly bigger

```
const BookList = () => {
  ...
  const renderItem = (item: any) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image 
          source={{uri: item.smallThumbnail}}
          style={styles.image} resizeMode='stretch' />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList style={styles.list}
        data={books}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        numColumns={3}
        renderItem={({item}) => renderItem(item)}
      />
    </View>
  );
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  list: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1/3,
    margin: 5
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    aspectRatio: 6 / 9
  }
});
```

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFpNh.png)

tried margin on image not imageContainer, this gave even more inconsistant spacing, like more vertically then horizontally and none at the left.

Answer (score 0):

`margin` in the container affects the width of the element(s). Move `margin` to image style.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={[...Array(5).keys()].map((i) => `https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=${i}`)}
        numColumns={3}
        renderItem={({item}) =>   
          <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item}}/>
          </View>
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1/3
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    aspectRatio: 6 / 9,
    margin: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this, it messes up everything even more

Comment: Your example has the same issue i have, more horizontal margin, none at the left...